# Concatenate in $state.go

Tags: angularjs, select, ionic-framework

I have in app.js the code below:

```
.state('app.a')...
.state('app.b')...
.state('app.c')...
```

Well, in one html I have a select option and the values are a,b,c with ng-model="activity.name"... I want click in them and go to their state. I try with this but it is wrong:

$state.go("app", $scope.activity.name)

Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `$state.go("app." + $scope.activity.name);`

Comment: ohhh, I am stupid, I tried this without '.'

Thank you very much!